# How many different regular icosahedra can be made by assigning numbers from 1 to 20 to the faces?

Tags: combinatorics

"How many different regular icosahedra is it possible to make assigning numbers from 1 to 20 to its faces? Suppose all faces indistinguishable."

I was trying to solve it as following: the total number will be $20!/x$, considering that rotations are possible and using simple permutations I would count the same icosahedron "$x$" times. The problem is to find the value of $x$.

Comment: If you specify one face to be invariant, $x=20y$, but this still does not account for rotations around the axis through the face. Then if you specify one other face which is not the face opposite the invariant face to be invariant, that completely specifies the orientation of the isocahedron. Thus $y=18$ and $x=360$ so the total number of choices is $20!/360$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: You have the right idea, but I think you vastly overcounted the rotational symmetries of the icosahedron.  There should be 60, not 360; picking one face and one edge incident to that face is sufficient to describe a rotation of the icosahedron.

Comment: @tmyklebu Thanks, I have edited my comment into an answer with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify one face to be invariant, x=20y, but this still does not account for rotations around the axis through the face. Then if you specify one other adjacent face which is not the face opposite the invariant face to be invariant, that completely specifies the orientation of the isocahedron. Thus since there are three adjacent faces, y=3 and x=60 so the total number of choices is 20!/60.

(This is a corrected version of a comment posted when the question was on hold. Thanks to tmyklebu for pointing out an error.)

Comment: Thank you, no it seems clear...

Answer (score 2):

There are three numbers surrounding the face with "20" on it. Choose them: $\tbinom{19}3$ and decide whether they increase clockwise or anticlockwise: $2$, then place the other numbers on the icosahedron which is now fixed: $16!$

Result: $\tbinom{19}3\cdot2\cdot16!=\tfrac13\cdot19!$